# Max row count in MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: sql, postgresql

How many rows can be stored in postgresql MATERIALIZED VIEW?

Comment: As many as in a regular table.

Comment: You are asking about PostgreSQL , so please don't tag the question `[oracle]`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about materialized views from this perspective. As many rows that can be returned by a query can be stored in a materialized view, assuming you have the storage space for it.